# Apply CSS same as legend tag

Tags: html, css, legend

I want to create a border around my html component. HTML legend element can be used but i want to use it out of the form.

HTML Legend:   http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset

I tried but there is an issue title and border. Below is the jsfiddle for the same.

```
.temp {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alpeshprajapati/a6a93fg9/1/

How can i achieve output same as legend ? Thanks.

Comment: Would adding `background-color: white;` to `.temp > span` get the result you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/a6a93fg9/3/

Comment: great @HiddenHobbes .. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, as this is what you are after I've created an answer with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty much there. The last step to make your markup look like a `legend` would be to add a `background-color` to the `span` which matches the `background-color` of `.temp` and the element that contains it. This ensures that the `border` or `.temp` does not show behind the text (as `background-color` is `transparent` by default).

```css
.temp > span {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
  left: 2%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
}
.temp {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="temp">
  <span>Permissions</span>
  <table class="table cs-table-no-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Modules</th>
        <th class="text-center">Edit</th>
        <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
        <th class="text-center">View</th>
        <th class="text-center">All</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>M1</td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```